# Xcode Make Callout of Annotation clickable

Tags: ios, xcode, mapkit

How can I achieve, that the user is able to tap on the whole callout (like in the Map App from Apple). I've just find solution when the user clicks on the rightAccessory Item.

Thank you in advance.

Chris

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133034/allow-tapping-anywhere-on-an-annotation-callout-without-a-callout-accessory-view

Comment: Thanks to gWiz:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133034/allow-tapping-anywhere-on-an-annotation-callout-without-a-callout-accessory-view